# Can JavaScript be updated less frequently?

Tags: feature-request, javascript

I'm using Firefox.  If I don't explicitly flush the cache, it will not handle updated JavaScript.  This is annoying.  I often load Stack Overflow pages and find I cannot vote until I flush the cache and re-load.

Could Stack Overflow reduce the frequency with which it updates the site's JavaScript — to, say, once per month or less?  This will reduce the frequency with which I am forced to manually flush the Firefox cache.

Comment: Windows XP/Ubuntu 'Lucid' with Firefox 3.6.x here, I don't have this issue.

Comment: No need to flush the entire cache, just CTRL+F5 the site

Comment: I do the bulk of my SO browsing using Firefox, and have *never* experienced this... You should investigate any caching proxies that might be sitting twixt you and SO.

Answer (score 2):

Updated javascripts not being automatically and transparently updated is a bug. We have cache breakers, if any are missing we will add.

We do not update our scripts too often, last month there were a fair bit of changes due to jQuery updates, image uploads and other stuff.

If we discover a bug that needs fixing in a js file, we fix it and deploy it. We also will not back log a bunch of finished features just because we are afraid of updating a js file.